# ImageMagick Text Arc

Tags: bash, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to take an image, say front2.jpg and add "Hello World" arc'd across the top. But I can't seem to figure out how to get this working. I'm getting an errror

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Command

```
convert front5.jpg (-gravity north -pointsize 40 -fill '#ffffff' -background none label:'Hello World' -virtual-pixel transparent -distort Arc 320) -geometry +0+0 -composite front2.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like bash is trying to tell you: take out the parentheses.

```
convert front5.jpg -gravity north -pointsize 40 -fill '#ffffff' -background none label:'Hello World' -virtual-pixel transparent -distort Arc 320 -geometry +0+0 -composite front2.jpg
```

I grabbed a random jpg and tried this command on it and got a neat little text arc (that's a pretty cool effect by the way) on the result.

It also works if you escape the parens, but I can't find any noticeable difference in the result, so I'd just use the first one for simplicity.

```
convert front5.jpg \( -gravity north -pointsize 40 -fill '#ffffff' -background none label:'Hello World' -virtual-pixel transparent -distort Arc 320 \) -geometry +0+0 -composite front2.jpg
```

Comment: Which one is the background? The first one or the last?